# google maps v3 wikipedia layer

Tags: google-maps

How could I implement the wikipedia layer on gmaps v3? I only managed to use the panoramio example. Could it be that they didn't support it on v3? In that case, how could I emulate the w-layer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it worked in v2
but apparently Wikipedia dosn't support Google Maps anymore

> [CNET: Wikipedia dumps Google Maps](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57410234-93/wikipedia-dumps-google-maps/)